Can a software company turn off their license server preventing further use of purchased licenses?
Today, Finale by MakeMusic made an announcement that they are discontinuing their software. Although it makes perfect sense that they won't be issuing updates or allowing new purchases, this line stuck me as odd

After one year, beginning August 2025, these changes will go into effect:
It will not be possible to authorize Finale on any new devices, or reauthorize Finale

Given MakeMusic sold permanent licenses to their software, not subscription licenses, can they legally "brick" all copies of their software?
Note: Although this questions stems from MakeMusic's announcement, I am curious about the idea in general, and how TOS/EULA might affect this.

From the quote, you are not stopped from using the software. Just that you can use it on new devices.

@RohitGupta, Finale requires re-auth every so often. Especially if you haven't used it in awhile.

@RohitGupta If it became impossible to use my music software on a new phone from today, then in a year or two I wouldn’t be able to buy a new phone, and I’d be forced to carry two phones to use a new one, and in 4-6 years I wouldn’t have working music software anymore.
